# How to visualize phylogeographical data?

Tags: data-visualization, biostatistics

I am working on phylogeography on one model species and I am a beginner. You can imagine one species that came on locality more than 5 mya (million years ago). It was a good environment, so the species expanded very quickly. After climatic changes this model species split in two refugiums (isolated locations for a once widespread species) and evolved into two species. This happened several times and now we have from that one ancestral species six valid species.

I have data from MrBayes. Can you recommend some phylogeographical program which can consider also expansion and contraction of model species?

**My input data:**

- coordinates (lat, lon) for each species
- geographical data of a continent (altitude, precipitation etc.)

**My  goal:**

Create a map where will be polygons (areas) of each species. These areas will expand and contract (step-by-step not like a do not want create video).

**My problem:**

I am able to make polygons by MCP, or kernel density, but unable to incorporate barriers into model.  For example, polygons of species which lives in mountain region created by MCP include areas of lowland inside...

Comment: @Ladislav - was undoing my extensive corrections of the English and explanation of abbrevations and jargon deliberate or the side effect of a long edit?

Comment: You have my deep apology @Glen_b, it is a side effect of a long edit. I will add your grammar corrections.

Comment: @Ladislav No problem. I wanted to be sure before I tried again, but if you're willing to do it, I'll leave you to it. Actually it looks like tatiana has already fixed the title.

Comment: @Glen_b I will fix the grammar exactly according to your first edit.

Comment: @Ladislav It's probably not needed - conjugateprior pretty much  took care of everything important